# Api level in googleplay console

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, google-play-console

I put on the manifest on the app minSDK and targetSDK
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm6dz.png)

google play console says that the Api Level is 24+ and target api is 30. I wanted to know if there any posibilites to put this app available minimum for android 6. Cause when I try to download the app using android 9 (For example) playstore says that my device is not available for this version of the app.

Thanks

Comment: API 24 is Android 7.0, so your phone on Android 9 should be eligible based on the Android SDK version. I suspect your device is not eligible for a different reason, e.g. device feature not available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.